# How to remove duplicate data in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 50
                    [cost] => 8320
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => transportation and others cost: 100  
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:09:20
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 3000
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:10:36
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 2000
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:10:58
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 6
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [id] => 4
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 50
                    [cost] => 8000
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-23 01:10:10
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove duplicate entry of `[Import][product_id]`. So my expected result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [amount] => 50
                    [cost] => 8320
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => transportation and others cost: 100  
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:09:20
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Import] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [id] => 2
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [amount] => 15
                    [cost] => 3000
                    [paid] => 0
                    [comment] => 
                    [created] => 2015-06-22 12:10:36
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [total_sell] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Would you write a function to filter this type of array and produce expected result. I have been googling for 2 days but no luck.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: When encountering semi-duplicates, which version of `product_id` do you want to keep in the final result? It looks like "first encountered". Is that right?

Comment: Yes. "first encountered" will be kept in final result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a handy one liner that should do the trick:

```
$unique= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $original)));
```

If the underlying arrays are not identical, that won't work, in which case I think you could do:

```
$unique = array_intersect_key($original ,
              array_unique(
                  array_map(function($item) {
                      return $item['Import']['product_id'];
                  }, $original)
              )
           );
```

Tested: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8aee5cbd614e0ddd1a03dfaa7e98c72fbbe7d68d

Comment: Will this work if only the `product_id`'s are the same, but other values are not the same? (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: $unique= array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $old_array)));  This does not work for me

Comment: We should ask the OP how he decides which version of `product_id` he wants to keep in the final result. It looks like "first encountered"

Comment: Yes. "first encountered" will be kept in final result

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick [stable sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and [reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) which runs in [linearithmic](https://www.wordnik.com/words/linearithmic) time. First-encountered product Id's are kept, and entries with duplicate product Id's are ignored.

```
// Stable sort
sort($in);

// Reduce
$out = array_reduce($in, function(&$acc, &$item){ 
    if($item['Import']['product_id'] !== @$acc[sizeof($acc)-1]['Import']['product_id']) {
       $acc[] = $item;    
    }
    return $acc;
}, []);
```

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/BP0eUJ

---

**Update:** Here is an even better linear-time algorithm that does the same as above using a fast "hash table" lookup. Again, the first-encountered product Id is kept and subsequent ones of the same Id are ignored.

```
$out = []; 
$hashTable = [];
foreach($in as $item) {
  $pid = $item['Import']['product_id'];
  if(!isset($hashTable[$pid])) {
    $out[] = $item; 
    $hashTable[$pid] = true;
  }
}
```

**Demo:** http://ideone.com/5RF0og